# How to obtain the Standard Deviation of a ratio of independent binomial random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

X and Y are 2 independent binomial random variables with parameters (n,p) and (m,q) respectively.
(trials, probability parameter)

Comment: Isn't there positive probability that this ratio is undefined?

Comment: Might be related to this article: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2531405

Answer (score 6):

There probably isn't a closed-form formula for this.

But $X$ has mean $np$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$, and $Y$ has mean $mq$ and standard deviation $mq(1-q)$.

Now you need a simple fact: if $X$ has mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, then $\log X$ has mean approximately $\log \mu$ and standard deviation approximately $\sigma/\mu$.  This can be derived by [Taylor expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables). Intuitively, $X$ "usually" falls in $[\mu-\sigma, \mu+\sigma]$ and so $\log X$ "usually" falls in $[\log (\mu-\sigma), \log (\mu+\sigma)]$. But we have

$$ \log (\mu \pm \sigma) = \log \Big(\mu(1 \pm \sigma/\mu)\Big) = \log \mu \pm \log(1 \pm \sigma/\mu) \approx \log \mu \pm \sigma/\mu $$

where the approximation is the first-order Taylor expansion of $\log (1+x)$ for $x$ close to zero.

Therefore $\log X$ has mean approximately $\log np$ and standard deviation approximately $\sqrt{(1-p)/np}$. Note that for the Taylor expansion above to be sufficient, $\sigma/\mu=\sqrt{(1-p)/np}$ must be close to zero. Similarly $\log Y$ has mean approximately $\log mq$ and standard deviation approximately $\sqrt{(1-q)/mq}$.

So $\log X - \log Y = \log X/Y$ has mean approximately $\log(np/mq)$ and standard deviation approximately
$$ \sqrt{{(1-p) \over np} + {(1-q) \over mq}}. $$

But you asked about $X/Y$. Inverting the earlier fact, if $Z$ has mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, then $e^Z$ has mean approximately $e^{\mu}$ and standard deviation approximately $\sigma e^\mu$. Therefore $X/Y$ has mean approximately $np/mq$ (not surprising!) and standard deviation approximately

$$ \left( \sqrt{{(1-p) \over np} + {(1-q) \over mq}} \right)  {np \over mq}. $$

This approximation works well if $p,q$ and/or $m,n$ are not too small (see Taylor expansion explanation in the middle of this answer).

Answer (score 3):

If $n$ and $m$ go to infinity while $p$ and $q$ are fixed, then the ratio $R=X/Y$ is well defined on an event of probability $1-o(1)$.

On this event (or conditionally on this event, since the two asymptotically equivalent), Edgeworth expansions of $X$ and $Y$ show that the expectation of $R$ behaves like $\dfrac{np}{mq}$ and that its variance behaves like
$$
\left(\frac{np}{mq}\right)^2\left(\frac{1-p}{np}+\frac{1-q}{nq}\right).
$$

Comment: "Edgeworth expansions of ..." Can you please any reference (book, paper, link?) that the expansion shows the mean of ratio approximately equal to the ratio of the mean?

Answer (score 1):

In essence you are asking for the distribution of the variable Z = X/Y, where Z can take values in $\left\{ 0, \frac{1}{m}, \ldots, \frac{n}{1}, \infty \right\}$, where the fractions are of the form $\frac{k}{l}$ with $0 \leq k \leq n$, and $1 \leq l \leq m$, and I'm assuming the convention $\frac{k}{0} = \infty$, which as Guy pointed out means this will be undefined, and the standard deviation will be infinite. So instead condition that this cannot happen
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[Z = k/l | Y \neq 0 \right] = \frac{\mathbb{P}[Xl = YK \cap Y \neq 0]}{\mathbb{P}[Y \neq 0]}
$$
So then this gives,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left[Z = k/l | Y \neq 0 \right] & = (1- (1-q)^m) \mathbb{P}[ Xl = Yk \cap Y \neq 0]\\
& = (1-(1-q)^m) \sum p^i(1-p)^{(n-i)}q^j(1-q)^{(m-j)}
\end{align}
$$
where the sum is over all pairs $(i,j)$ with $0 \leq i \leq n$, $0 < j \leq m$ such that $i/j = k/l$... All in all it looks like its going to be a messy task to compute this sum, and to find the standard deviation.

Answer (score 0):

This shoud be a comment over Michael Lugo's answer. The Taylor expansion approach can be done directly, without taking logarithm and inverting.

In general, for a diferentiable $g(y)$ and a small variance random variable $Y$ we have

$$ Z = g(Y) \approx g(\mu_Y) + g'(\mu)(Y-\mu_Y) + \frac{1}{2}g''(\mu)(Y-\mu_Y)^2 + \cdots$$

$$ \mu_Z \approx g(\mu_Y) + \frac{1}{2}g''(u_Y)\sigma_Y^2 + \cdots \tag 1 $$

and

$$ \sigma_Z^2 \approx [g'(\mu_Y)]^2   \sigma_Y^2  \tag 2$$

In particular, for $g(Y)=1/Y$:

$$  \mu_Z \approx \frac{1}{\mu_Y} +  \frac{\sigma_Y^2}{\mu_Y^3}  $$

$$  \sigma_Z^2 \approx \frac{\sigma_Y^2}{\mu_Y^4}$$

Then, assuming $X,Y$ are independent:

$$E[X/Y] =E[X] E[1/Y] \approx \frac{\mu_X}{\mu_Y} + \mu_X\frac{\sigma_Y^2}{\mu_Y^3} \approx \frac{\mu_X}{\mu_Y}$$

Also, using [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15978/variance-of-product-of-dependent-variables):
$${\rm Var} (X/Y) \approx \sigma_X^2 \frac{\sigma_Y^2}{\mu_Y^4} + 
\sigma_X^2 (\frac{\mu_X}{\mu_Y})^2 + \frac{\sigma_Y^2}{\mu_Y^4} \mu_X^2 \approx 
\frac{\mu_X^2}{\mu_Y^2}\left(\frac{\sigma_X^2}{\mu_X^2} + \frac{\sigma_Y^2}{\mu_Y^2}\right)$$