# Expected value of division of sums of Bernoullis

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, proof-writing, binomial-distribution

Let $B_i\sim Bernoulli(p)$ be $n$ i.i.d Bernoulli random variables and $C_j\sim Bernoulli(1-p)$ be $n$ more i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables.

I would like to calculate:

$$E\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i B_i + \sum_{j=1}^n b_j C_j}{\sum_{i=1}^n B_i + \sum_{j=1}^n C_j}\right]$$

with $a_i$ and $b_j$ be all in $[-1, 1]$. I'm particularly interested in the case $b_j=0$, $\forall j=1,\ldots,n$.

I figured that the sum of the denominator follows a Poisson Binomial distribution with mean $n$.

I've checked empirically and it seems that when $b_j=0$, the expected value is $p\cdot \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$, but I want to prove it formally. If I could separate into the division of expectations, everything would check out, but I know that, in general, that doesn't hold.

Is there any known result that can help with this?

Comment: You should use a different letter for your second set of Bernoulli random variables i.e. let $C_j \sim \textrm{Ber}(1-p)$. Otherwise the notation is ambiguous

Comment: Thanks @JackT. I fixed it.

Comment: How do you define the ratio when the denominator is zero with probability $p^n (1-p)^n$?

Comment: +1 That's a good point, @heropup I'm considering large $n$'s so that probability is very small. What is a reasonable approach to tackle a problem like this when the random variable in the denominator can be zero? Is there perhaps a way to approximate it for large $n$'s?

Comment: Hmm perhaps using the CLT?

Comment: Or let's assume that we consider the denominator + 1, would then there be an approach to tackle the problem?

Answer (score 1):

For large $n$, and disregarding  the event where the denominator is zero (the probability should turn negligible), we can assume the numerator and denominator behave as two independent approximately gaussian variables.

Now we use [this reasoning](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/60175/312): if we have $Z=X/Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent then (asympotically, under certain conditions):

$$ \mu_Z \approx \mu_X/\mu_Y$$
$$ \sigma^2_Z \approx \frac{\mu_X^2}{\mu_Y^2}\left( \frac{\sigma_X^2}{\mu_X^2} +\frac{\sigma_Y^2}{\mu_Y^2} \right)$$

In our case

$$ \mu_X = A n  p + B n (1-p) \hskip{1cm} \sigma^2_X= (A' + B')np(1-p) $$
$$ \mu_Y = n p + n (1-p) =n \hskip{1cm} \sigma^2_Y= 2np(1-p) $$

where $A=\frac{1}{n}\sum a_i$ , $A'= \frac{1}{n}\sum a_i^2$ etc. Notice that $|A| \le 1$, $|A'| \le 1$.

(Granted, our $X,Y$ are not really independent, but we can expect that at least the expression for the mean is still valid)

Then

$$\mu_Z \approx A p + B(1-p)$$

which reduces (for $B=0$) to your empirical result.

As for the variance:

$$\sigma_Z^2 \approx \frac{p(1-p)}{n} \left[\left( 2 {{B}^{2}}-4 A B+2 {{A}^{2}}\right)  {{p}^{2}}+\left( 4 A B-4 {{B}^{2}}\right)  p+{B'}+2 {{B}^{2}}+{A'} \right]  \to 0$$

Comment: Thanks @leonbloy This is useful! How could I theoretically bound the error of this approximation for a specific n?

Comment: I think This kind of asymptotic approximation is difficult to bound.

Comment: Wouldn't the bounds for Taylor expansions apply here?